# I have changed memory size in eclipse but I'm still getting the java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, memory, memory-management, heap-memory

I'm running a Java program which reads line by line from a file as big as 1.2 GB and at some point it tries to put them in a hash. After some time after calling the taxhash.put(tmpgi,tmptax) it gives me the java.lang.OutOfMemoryError error.

I tried and changed the eclipse.ini options as follow

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.1.R36x_v20101122_1400.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.2.R36x_v20101222
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
512M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
512m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms2048m
-Xmx3548m
```

and BTW I'm running my code on a 64bit win 7 with 4GB ram. and here is the code for reading from the file!

```
boolean readfile(String filename,int verbose){
        //this should read the inputfile and save the data in it to the gitax array.
        taxhash=new HashMap();
        int currnum=0;
        try{
            BufferedReader inread=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
            String instring;
            String[] tmparr;
            Integer tmpgi;
            Integer tmptax;
            if(verbose>0){
                while ((instring=inread.readLine())!=null){
                    currnum++;
                    instring=instring.trim();
                    tmparr=instring.split("\\s+",0);//split on one or more whitespaces
                    //now I should have two elements in this array, the gi number and the taxid
                    if(java.lang.reflect.Array.getLength(tmparr)!=2){
                        System.err.println("Error reading from "+filename+" "+java.lang.reflect.Array.getLength(tmparr)+" elements.");
                    }else{
                        try{
                            tmpgi=Integer.valueOf(tmparr[0]);
                            tmptax=Integer.valueOf(tmparr[1]);
                        }catch (NumberFormatException e){
                            System.err.println("unable to parse number from "+tmparr[0]+" "+tmparr[1]);
                            return false;
                        }
                        taxhash.put(tmpgi,tmptax);
                    }
                    if(currnum==100000){
                        System.out.print(".");
                        currnum=0;
                    }
                }
            }else{
                while ((instring=inread.readLine())!=null){
                    instring=instring.trim();
                    tmparr=instring.split("\\s+",0);//split on one or more whitespaces
                    //now I should have two elements in this array, the gi number and the taxid
                    if(java.lang.reflect.Array.getLength(tmparr)!=2){
                        System.err.println("Error reading from "+filename+" "+java.lang.reflect.Array.getLength(tmparr)+" elements.");
                    }else{
                        try{
                            tmpgi=Integer.valueOf(tmparr[0]);
                            tmptax=Integer.valueOf(tmparr[1]);
                        }catch (NumberFormatException e){
                            System.err.println("unable to parse number from "+tmparr[0]+" "+tmparr[1]);
                            return false;
                        }
                        taxhash.put(tmpgi,tmptax);
                    }
                }
            }
        }catch (IOException e){
            System.err.println("IOError in reading from "+filename);
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }// end readfile
```

this is the the error in more details Exception in thread "main"

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.HashMap.resize(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.HashMap.addEntry(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.HashMap.put(Unknown Source)
    at com.ali.Blammer.taxid.readfile(taxid.java:79)
    at com.ali.Blammer.taxid.readfile(taxid.java:50)
    at com.ali.Blammer.main.run(main.java:182)
    at com.ali.Blammer.blammer.main(blammer.java:36)
    at com.ali.Interface.main.main(main.java:53)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are changing the memory options that affect the `eclipse` JVM, not the memory options of the program that you run.

In the Run configuration, the second tab allows setting JVM parameters for the run execution. Anyway, I doubt that you will get to put a 1.2GB of file (plus hashes and other overheads) in 512 MB

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the size of your program not eclipse.  Since you are storing 1.2 GB of text you need at least 2.4 Gb of memory but I suspect closer to 4 GB is required (with overhead)

Since you have a small machine, I suggest you process the file progressively to minimise memory consumption if you can.

BTW: You could use TIntIntHashMap which would be much smaller than HashMap (up to 4x smaller), but could still be too much for your data set.

Comment: thanks but what do you mean by "process the file progressively to minimise memory consumption if you can."

Comment: Instead of reading the whole file, before using the information, it is often possible to use a portion of the file and use that, and then reading some more etc. This assumes you can break it up that way.